# How to exclude an ID column from a class in C# for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Maybe title question is very simple but I have met another issue regarding excluding a property from another class.

As I know, the `Bind(Exclude="ID")` attribute is available only for the class, not property.

Let's assume that I have the following model:

```
public class AModel 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public Language Lang { get; set; }
}
```

Following class is a part of DLL (cannot change anyting inside it), I will show you his definition

```
public class Language 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Eng { get; set; }
    public string Fra { get; set; }
    public string Ned { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

How is possible to exclude column ID to be not shown in View using `@Html.EditorForModel()` method ?

something like:

```
public class AModel 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [Exclude(ID)]
   public Language Lang { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either can use custom [editor template](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/672591/Exploring-Display-and-Editor-Templates-in-ASP-NET) for your class, or you can create `LanguageModel` which don't have id, and map `Language` object to that model ([Automapper](http://automapper.org/) is a good option).

UPDATE (mapping sample)

```
public class AModel 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public LanguageModel Lang { get; set; }
}

public class LanguageModel
{
    // No ID
    public string Eng { get; set; }
    public string Fra { get; set; }
    public string Ned { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Create mapping between language model and domain language class (you can add it to *Global.asax*)

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Language, LanguageModel>();
```

Thus properties have exactly same names, you don't need anything else. When assigning language to your `AModel` instance, use mapper:

```
Language lang = GetLanuage();
var model = new AModel {
    Name = "Foo",
    Lang = Mapper.Map<LanguageModel>(lang)
};
```

One more benifit here is that you can add data annotations or other stuff you need without changing domain class.

Comment: How to map `Language` ? I tried to find it but no results. Thanks

Comment: @SnakeEyes I've added sample of mapping

Comment: Wow, nice. I will try this :)